# How to define binary in another binary?

Tags: erlang

```
A = <<"hello">>.
B = <<A:80/binary, 100:8>>.
```

It gives me:

> ** exception error: bad argument

and `<<"hello">>.` works, but:

```
A = "hello".
<<A>>.
```

can not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`A` doesn't have size 80 bytes which obviously doesn't match `A:80/binary` in first case.

```
1> A = <<"hello">>.
<<"hello">>
2> B = <<A/binary, 100:8>>.
<<"hellod">>
3> Pad = 80 - size(A), C = <<A/binary, 0:Pad/unit:8, 100:8>>.
<<104,101,108,108,111,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  0,0,0,0,0,0,...>>
```

`<<"hello">>` is syntactic sugar for `<<$h,$e,$l,$l,$o>>`. Bit syntax expression assumes `8/integer,unsigned,big,unit:1` type specification by default. `A` is not integer so `<<A>>` raises `badarg` exception in second case.

Comment: A = "hello". <<A:5/binary>>. is ok

Comment: @why: See [documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id77447) for defaults. `binary` has default value `unit:8` according to documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The value <<"Hello">> works but only because "Hello" is a string literal. When you write,

```
  A = "Hello",
```

you are creating a String object, which is really a list of unicode codepoints. Now, when you declare,

```
  <<A>>
```

then `A` is assumed to be an integer because the is the default. Naturally something is wrong when you try to inject a list/string for an integer, which is the reason for the badarg.

The solution is two-fold:

```
  list_to_binary(A)
```

will convert the list to a binary. Now you have the equivalent of `<<A/binary>>` and you can manipulate it:

```
   L = byte_size(A),
   <<L:32/integer, A/binary>>
```